# Probability Distribution of Total Value of Jar of Coins given its Weight

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayesian

Suppose I have a jar of coins, of which I know the total weight.
Furthermore, I know the weights of the different types of coins (and also assume they are pairwise distinct).

Given the total weight (say, within some margin), is it possible to obtain a probability distribution function (analytically) for the total *value* of all the coins? If so, how?

Comment: Not without more information, no.

Comment: @BenW Would you mind briefly explaining why that is?

Comment: You need a rule for applying probabilities, and you don't have one here.